# Convert pem key to p12 when having 1 key and 1 pem

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssh

I'm having a hard time creating a p12 key. Here are the steps I did:

1: openssl genrsa -out priv.key 4096
2: openssl req -new -sha256 -key priv.key -out priv.csr
3: Converted the csr into a priv.pem file from a website specially for this (payment gateway).

And here I'm stuck. According to [this website](https://help.hcltechsw.com/appscan/Standard/9.0.3/en-US/t_ConvertthepfxCertificatetopemFormat068.html) following code can be used:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out Cert.p12 -in cert.pem -inkey key.pem -passin pass:root -passout pass:root
```

The problem for me is: I only have **one** pem key but the above requires two. So can I with only my pem key now convert it into a p12 key with password?

Comment: **PEM IS A FORMAT NOT A CONTENT.** Your `priv.key` file output from `genrsa` is a privatekey in PEM format; what you got from the 'gateway' _should_ be a certificate or certificate chain in PEM format. Those are the two things you need as input to `openssl pkcs12 -export`. If not, _look_ at the `priv.pem` file you got from the 'gateway' and describe what is actually in it, for advice on what is or is not possible.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thank you for the answer. Inside the PEM file are 3 "Begin/end" certificates. Does that help? Cause when I try to only use the one key and one PEM it gives me error. So not sure of the correct command to use.

Comment: If they are the _correct_ 3 certificates it should work. (I feel a bit like Liza Minelli.) Put each one in a separate file and do `openssl x509 <file -noout -text` to see which is which, and verify the modulus in the 'leaf' cert matches the one in your privatekey (with `openssl rsa <priv.key -noout -modulus`). PS: I didn't notice, but don't tag 'openssh'; you are using openssl, which is a separate and different thing from openssh, even though having some letters in common.